# Not able to push image to private docker registry

Tags: docker

After setting up a private docker registry on a server within my network, I'm not able to push images to it. Setup was done as following:

1. setup a private docker registry according to [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)
2. got a ssl certificate by the hosting-provider for the desired domain
3. created a directory `/certs` on the registry server (192.x.x.x) and placed `.cert` and `.key` files there
4. added domain to my local machine's host file `192.x.x.x example.com`
5. able to ping the server using the domain
6. tagged an image as `example.com/my-image` and tried to push

But I'm always getting the error `Get https://example.com/v2/ Bad Gateway`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to authenticate to the repository you are trying to push the image to.
Docker Command: `docker login <address_to_your_repository>`. It should prompt you for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The docker documentation shows that docker registry is started on port 5000, while your tag/push seems to not take that into account.

I would try to 2 things:

- check from the client that you can access the port of the server on which you started the registry. A command like "curl example.com:5000" should not say connection refused
- include the port in the tag, meaning use "example.com:5000/my-image" if you used port 5000